# Thinkpad 13 2G - i7-7500U - NVME timeout aborting

Tags: kernel, filesystem, nvme

I replace HD in my thinkpad, after this I have the following problem every 2 or 3 days resulting in a read only "root" or "home" volume/partition.

---

Kernel version is:

```
4.11.1-041101-generic
```

And SSD is:

```
nvme Intel 600p NVMe SSD 1TB
```

I'm still investigating the problem, but I found nothing obvious.

Here enclosed is dmesg captured just after the error:

```
[58842.192196] hid-generic 0003:062A:4102.000D: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input0
[67051.904993] nvme nvme0: I/O 201 QID 1 timeout, aborting
[67051.905010] nvme nvme0: I/O 202 QID 1 timeout, aborting
[67051.905015] nvme nvme0: I/O 203 QID 1 timeout, aborting
[67051.905019] nvme nvme0: I/O 211 QID 1 timeout, aborting
[67051.905023] nvme nvme0: I/O 212 QID 1 timeout, aborting
[67051.909007] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67051.909017] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67051.909034] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67052.897026] nvme nvme0: I/O 118 QID 3 timeout, aborting
[67052.897045] nvme nvme0: I/O 53 QID 4 timeout, aborting
[67052.897050] nvme nvme0: I/O 54 QID 4 timeout, aborting
[67052.897122] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67052.897129] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67052.897138] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67076.128805] nvme nvme0: I/O 55 QID 4 timeout, aborting
[67076.128832] nvme nvme0: I/O 56 QID 4 timeout, aborting
[67076.128904] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67076.128909] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67079.968884] nvme nvme0: I/O 137 QID 2 timeout, aborting
[67079.969042] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[67083.040795] nvme nvme0: I/O 201 QID 1 timeout, reset controller
[67083.177426] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177431] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1345495872
[67083.177456] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671784)
[67083.177460] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671784
[67083.177468] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671785
[67083.177472] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671786
[67083.177475] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671787
[67083.177478] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671788
[67083.177488] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177490] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1345495920
[67083.177499] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671790)
[67083.177501] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671790
[67083.177504] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671791
[67083.177507] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671792
[67083.177510] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671793
[67083.177513] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 105671794
[67083.177521] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177522] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1345496288
[67083.177530] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671836)
[67083.177540] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177542] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1345496352
[67083.177548] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671844)
[67083.177552] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1345496392
[67083.177556] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671849)
[67083.177562] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177564] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1132959960
[67083.177578] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177580] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 290693072
[67083.177597] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177599] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1247520968
[67083.177606] Aborting journal on device nvme0n1p5-8.
[67083.177618] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 9307036 at logical offset 60 with max blocks 1 with error 30
[67083.177627] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

[67083.177636] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5) in ext4_writepages:2808: IO failure
[67083.177772] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177775] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 1247521224
[67083.177795] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177798] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 386266720
[67083.177804] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 37224652, lost async page write
[67083.177822] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: 0007
[67083.177827] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p5, logical block 37224896, lost async page write
[67083.177837] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x7
[67083.177840] Aborting journal on device dm-0-8.
[67083.177846] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x7
[67083.177855] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5598: Journal has aborted
[67083.177861] nvme nvme0: completing aborted command with status: fffffffc
[67083.177868] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:313: I/O error -5 writing to inode 25299757 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 105671775)
[67083.177889] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 27158472 at logical offset 0 with max blocks 18 with error 30
[67083.177894] EXT4-fs (dm-0): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

[67083.177901] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_writepages:2808: Journal has aborted
[67083.177903] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5598: Journal has aborted
[67083.177915] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5598: Journal has aborted
[67083.177964] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5598: Journal has aborted
[67083.322771] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_da_write_end:3086: IO failure
[67083.324933] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): Remounting filesystem read-only
[67083.327103] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p5): ext4_journal_check_start:60: Detected aborted journal
[67083.341117] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_dirty_inode:5723: Journal has aborted
[67083.341373] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_do_update_inode:5080: Journal has aborted
[67083.341403] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_dirty_inode:5723: Journal has aborted
[67083.341557] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 25299724 at logical offset 0 with max blocks 1 with error 30
[67083.341565] EXT4-fs (dm-0): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

[67083.341574] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0) in ext4_writepages:2808: IO failure
[67083.341684] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:60: Detected aborted journal
[67083.341692] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[67083.343712] EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 9223372036854775806 pages, ino 26479410; err -30
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems latest kernel solved this problem. Actually running on:

- 4.11.3-041103-generic

It should work starting from 4.10 but I did't tested so much.